# Adjectival participles and perfect

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-aspect

I read a wonderful article on this resource about the Perfect construction - [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) - and came across this part:

> Adjectival participles
>
> The economy has neither completely recovered from the global recession which struck in 2008 nor remained permanently **stuck** in a **protracted** depression.
>
> ...
>
> Note that in one of the examples above, there are also past
> participles which are not part of the perfect construction—stuck and
> protracted. These are employed as adjectives—stuck as an adjective
> complement and protracted as an attributive adjective. That’s
> something else you have to watch out for.

Can someone clarify and provide examples of how constructions with Adjectival Participles, similar to the Perfect?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the "examples above" that contain the words "stuck" and "protracted". We can't explain how they're not perfect constructions if we can't see them. Don't expect answerers to follow links.

Comment: @gotube Ok, done

Comment: That paragraph could be a parenthetical note or removed entirely. It's certainly doesn't belong as part of the main body of a text about the usage of perfect forms, and has nothing to do with learning about them.

Comment: @gotube: I think you missed the point being made by StoneyB and repeated in my answer below. The OP *here* has mistakenly assumed the past participles "stuck" and "protracted" have some connection to Perfect verb forms in the context of StoneyB's post. Which is *exactly* the conflation he was advising people *not* to make - just because ***[HAVE] + [Past Participle]*** is called the "Perfect" form doesn't imply that ***[Past Participle]*** on its own has any particular relevance to Perfect forms. Usually  they're either Simple Past, OR (as his examples) Past Participles used ***adjectivally***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific context where ***stuck*** appears in StoneyB's excellent "Canonical Post" is...

> *The economy **has** neither completely **recovered** from the global recession which struck in 2008 nor **remained** permanently **stuck** in a protracted depression.*

There's nothing in the surrounding text about the use of ***stuck*** there being "similar to the Perfect", *because it's not*. It's a completely different type of verb usage, whereby the past participles ***stuck*** and ***protracted*** are used as ***adjectives***.

Note that the primary point of that particular example is simply to point out that ***remained*** is effectively a Present Perfect usage, even though it doesn't explicitly say ***has remained.*** The ***has*** is *implicit* - it's an "elided" repetition of ***has*** from the third word in the utterance (alternatively, *...nor **has** [it] remained...*).